# Is it possible to find out what template was used to create a site using the SOAP service?

Tags: 2010, wss-3.0, web-services, site-template, caml-query

I am connecting to a SharePoint 2010 server(which I don't control) using the SOAP service (.asmx)

I need a list of sites which were created using a certain template.
Is it possible to create a CAML query which will return something like "all sites created using template x"?

.. if that is not possible:
Given a site, is it possible to find out "what template was this site created with?"

.. if it is at all important, the client app is iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, i don't think this is possible... you will have to create a custom web service which reads the [WebTemplateId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.webtemplateid.aspx) property of the site. However, this will only give you the GUID of the template. If you want the name if it, you'll have to create a CAML query and query the Site Template Gallery.

Comment: fair enough. any idea if it is possible in the 2010 RESTful service?

Comment: i haven't tried it, but i don't think its possible either... the REST services are mostly used to query List/Library data